# merge cells based on value of another cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I've been working on a project and I'm trying to make things go smoother :)

I have an excel sheet with several columns and as you can see it below, Column C is the importance of the topic(based on information typed in that row) and Column D is whether the information typed is a new information or an update regarding the previous (upper) row. Soo:

if I type "update" on column D, row 3; I want it to automatically merge the cells C2 and C3.

```
     C      D
1   LOW     new
2   HIGH    new
3          update
4   Low     new
5          update
6          update
```

I don't know how to write VBA codes but I can mostly understand the codes enough to adopt what I find on internet to what I want to achieve. I have checked so many websites to find whatever I needed but I had no luck so I would really appreciate if you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Sub Merge_Priority()
Dim RgToMerge As String


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    RgToMerge = ""
    If LCase(Cells(i, 4)) <> "update" Or (LCase(Cells(i + 1, 4)) <> "new" And Cells(i + 1, 4) <> "") Then
    Else
        RgToMerge = "$C$" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlUp).Row & ":$C$" & i
        With Range(RgToMerge)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Do you know how to add a macro on an event?

Go to Visual Studio, select `ThisWorkBook` on the left and create a macro with this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
```

And paste the code right above

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I am sorry for the burden but I thought I would be able to edit the code you've posted and adapt it to my file and I actually couldn't do it. the column contains high and low values is on C, and new and update column is D. Could you please help me to change the code according to this info?

Comment: Changes done! ;)   If everything is working properly, plz validate the answer to close subject!

Comment: Everything was okay but I don't know how, with this code, when it merges the cells it merges from the top (C1) till the last row with "update" value and it merges all the column in one. Is there anyway to code it so that the cells will merge until the previous (upwards) "new" value?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change a column number in the definition of RgToMerge, give it a try now

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this add this Macro in the Current Sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

IF Target.value = "Update" then
     Range("A" & Target.row - 1 & ":A" & Target.row).Merge
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: With that you will only merge two cells, but indeed it will be launched at every change in the worksheet.